# Combined the Progress object with a custom event and not sure why it works but it does

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, win-universal-app

I'm trying to figure out why this works.  I create a custom event and a progress object that are fired from the none UI thread.  I placed the result event with in my custom event and the cross threading update to my UI still works.  This makes no sense.  The event fires and runs its code , how does the progress event fire within the other event.  I know this should never be done.  But I cant figure out logically why it works.

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pracViewModel myViewModel = new pracViewModel(5, "Hello");

        Progress<int> progress = new Progress<int>();

        myViewModel.triggerEvent += (i) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(i.ToString());

            progress.ProgressChanged += (o, result) =>
            {
                txtBlock1.Text = result.ToString();

            };

        };


        myViewModel.countAsync(progress);
    }




class pracViewModel
{
    public async void countAsync(Progress<int> progress)
    {
        await count(progress);
    }

    private Task count(IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
                progress.Report(i);
                triggerEvent(i);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Progress<T>` constructor captures the current `SynchronizationContext` - in this case, a UI context.

When your thread pool thread calls `Report`, `Progress<T>` will use that UI context, so the UI thread will raise `Progress<T>.ProgressChanged`.

Comment: But how does it fire within another event?  My setup up is basically an event within an event

Comment: @user3363744: Not at all. The "fire event" is just *subscribing* to the `ProgressChanged` event, not triggering it.

Comment: @user3363744 Please be sure to accept answers that satisfactorily solve your problem, by clicking the checkmark next to them. I noticed you haven't been doing that with your questions - please do! It helps to signal to the community that your answer has been successfully answered.